# mocking a directory subtree for pytest

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, pytest

I have recursive code to gather tests from given directory. It relies on few functions: isdir, isfile, and acess to files. It expects that directories can be listed with os.listdir.

To test this function I need to mock a lot of functions in very non-trivial way. Is any way to mock all os/os.path related thing in short way with given filelist? Something like "`mock_subdir(example_in_tar_gz):`" or with some kind of DSL to describe mocked directory tree structure.

Function of interest:

```
def gather_tests(path):
    if os.path.isdir(path):
        filelist = [os.path.join(path, f) for f in os.listdir(path)]
        filelist.sort()
        all_files = map(gather_tests, filelist)
        return filter(None, all_files)
    elif os.path.isfile(path) and os.access(path, os.X_OK):
        return path
    else:
        return None
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a temporary directory using the [pytest tmpdir fixture](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/tmpdir.html). It will be easier than mocking every functions.

Or if you really want to mock the functions, you only need to mock: isdir, listdir, isfile and access:

```
with mock.patch('module.isdir') as mock_isdir, \
        mock.patch('module.listdir') as mock_listdir, \
        mock.patch('module.iffile') as mock_isfile, \
        mock.patch('module.access') as mock_access:
    mock_isdir.return_value = True
    mock_listdir.return_value = ['file1', 'file2']
    mock_isfile.return_value = True
    mock_access.return_value = True
```